# What kind of actions trigger the below mentioned Cent OS logs

Tags: centos, systemd

```
systemd: Removed slice User Slice of
systemd: Stopping User Slice of
systemd: Created slice User Slice of
systemd: Starting User Slice of
```

Someone please be kind enough to explain me these logs one by one. Thank you very much

Comment: This might be helpful: [https://access.redhat.com/solutions/1564823](https://access.redhat.com/solutions/1564823)